# Automatic screen resolution in wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, resolution, screen-resolution

I have made an installer MSI using Wix, what I want to do is to auto resize the installer window according to the resolution of the screen (at least for a 2K and 4K machine).

Answer (score 0):

The sizes of Windows Installer dialogs are based on [Installer Units](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369490), not pixels, so in general they should automatically scale per a user's DPI setting.

If this is insufficient for your needs, you may be able to define parallel sequences of dialogs, and put conditions that examine [ScreenX, ScreenY, or other hardware properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905#hardware_properties) to control which initial dialog is shown. This will probably involve a lot of work to create the each dialog sequence at a different size, although it may be possible to write code to automate their generation.